# VBA: copy sheet without displaying it for a fraction of a second

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro on sheet "Index" if the macro is clicked I want to create a new sheet and copy in it a part from another sheet (called "Template").

I have the following code that does the job:

```
Set new_sheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Sheets("Template").Range("A1:Z100").Copy
Destination:=Sheets(new_sheet.Name).Range("A1")
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
Sheets("Index").Activate
```

However, I do not like that for a fraction of a second the new sheet is displayed (I find it a little bit disturbing, like a subliminal message). I would like to remain on the "Index" sheet. Hence,

a) is there a way to avoid the newly create sheet is displayed;

b) if the answer to a) is negative, is there a way to show a dialog box that last for a fraction of second like "Elaborating..." that hides what happens in background?

Comment: `Application.Screenupdating = False` just before you copy the sheet.

Comment: Ok that was perfect. Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Beat me too it, but also remember to turn it back on `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: I would just accept one of the answers

Comment: I have another issue, now. I change a value which is called by a vlookup and it shows a part of another sheet for a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ScreenUpdating` property to `True` or `False` to suit your needs with this at the beginning of your Sub:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And this at the end:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

somewhere before you do your copy

Answer (score 2):

Fully agree, you can use set the ScreenUpdating property to True or False as everyone has already mentioned. But you need to take caution. If you debug or the app bugs out while screenupdating is set to false, then it will cause the excel file to "freeze" - but not completely, just the screen. As it mentions, the screen does not update until you call it to be true again.

So, I would suggest to leave this out while developing. It can be very annoying to go back and forth to enable it manually in the code each time the program freeze.